# OpenGL app crashes on other PCs

Tags: opengl

I made an OpenGL app for testing out Framebuffer Objects that works on the laptop I made it on, another laptop I own and my desktop PC. However, it seems to crash for everyone else I've asked to test the app for me.

So far I have narrowed it down to crashing on the first extension I call (in this case, glGenBuffers), which I am 100% certain is not called until after this function (see below) is called. After looking through many answers, I have made sure of the following:

- I have checked that the window has been created.
- I call glewInit() after I create and set the context.
- glewExperimental is set to GL_TRUE.
- No gl extension is called before this function is completed.
- I have checked that glGenBuffers is not equal to null.

And it still crashes on other PCs, in this manner:

1. The window is created, white background - no clear colour.
2. A message box pops up, saying "application.exe has stopped responding"

Any ideas of what I can try next?

---

**Update:** Asked my friend to send me the error message, here it is:

*Unhandled exception at 0x7490CB49 in OpenGL Framework.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.*

---

```
    void CSystem::Initialise()
    {
        if(glfwInit() == GL_FALSE)
        {
            return GL_FALSE;
        }

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

        if(m_bFullscreen)
            window = glfwCreateWindow(1600, 900, "OpenGL", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr); // Fullscreen
        else
            window = glfwCreateWindow(1600, 900, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed

        if(window == nullptr)
        {
            return false;
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(glGetError())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whenever something is going wrong in an openGL program, one of the first things you should do is put `glGetError()` calls *all over the place*. That'll help you determine *which* call failed. Without that, the error code itself is meaningless.

Comment: Or, considering this is a GL 4.0 context, use synchronous debug output. You can trap API errors that way complete with the relevant callstack without inserting a bunch of `glGetError (...)` calls. Of course since debug output has to be loaded using `*GetProcAddress (...)` as well, it might create the same underlying problem ;)

Comment: As long as I wait until after I create the context, glGetError() always returns 0 - though that doesn't stop it from crashing.

Comment: The `Access violation executing location 0x00000000.` actually hints at the fact that that function pointer actually is NULL. "I have checked that glGenBuffers is not equal to null." Have you checked that on the actual machine where it is crashing, or just on your machine? My guess would be that the people you are testing this just don't have a proper GL>=3 implementation.

Comment: I asked to tester to add a if(glGenBuffers) wrapper around the function call and he says it enters the if statement and crashes in the same glGenBuffers call. Odd, right?

Comment: Everyone I've given to has at the very least a half decent nvidia card (500/600 series) with support for OpenGL 4.0-4.3, so it can't just be as simple as not being able to support the app right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix the issue, for anyone else who wants to know. Turns out that even though GLEW didn't bring up any errors, it still wasn't loading all the extensions properly.

I solved the issue by removing GLEW entirely and writing my own extension loader. Time consuming, and probably not what other people with the same problem want to hear - but that did it.

It was good at least for me to write something so that in the future I can actually see which extensions are failing to load and how. In this case, by writing them all myself it ended up working flawlessly. Go figure!

Comment: I don't know what went wrong in your original code, but I highly doubt that GLEW is _that_ broken. It is in wide use, and nobody ever reported such a problem. There must be something triggering this behavior, in your code.

Comment: There are numerous extension loaders other than GLEW.

Comment: I never said GLEW was broken, I just said it wasn't working. I realise there are other extension loaders, but I feel much better using my own - as I don't have to worry about "is this supported", or "is that supported".